# How to instance a custom ArrayAdapter during the doInBackground of an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

i have a listview with a custom arrayadapter. each row of the list have also a gallery with her own adapter. so everything works fine. but scrolling fast the list, it stagnates because each row must load the the secound adapter of the gallery. this are only millisecounds, but you feel ist, because the list don't scroll smooth. so i would like to load the secound arrayadapter of the gallery in an asynctask, so that the scrolling in not influence. but their is the problem:

in the doInBackground-method i want to do this:

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(activity, R.layout.items, arraylist);
```

but there he throws me a futuretask error. i thing it is the "activity" that is the problem. can i solve it? or is their no chance?

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using non-reusable ListView adapters. Using them will improve application speed as it will reuse resources and you will avoid garbage collecting. Find out more at: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/, especially look at OrderAdapter implementation.

You won't be able to modify view in **doInBackground** as it is not invoked on the UI thread. Please refer to Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html